# Does integration by parts hold with $f$ not differentiable for the Riemann-Stieltjes integral?

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Suppose $f$ is a strictly increasing, continuous function over $\mathbb{R}$, and $f(0) = 0$, $b > 0$. I need to show that for the change of variable $x = f(t)$,

$$\int_0^b f^{-1}(x)\,dx =\int_{0}^{f^{-1}(b)} t\,df(t) =bf^{-1}(b)-\int_0^{f^{-1}(b)}f(t)\,dt.$$ This looks like integration by parts, but we don't know how if $f$ is differentiable. Is the above true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question covers a lot of ground.

First, because $f$ is strictly increasing, the inverse $f^{-1}$ must be a strictly increasing continuous function. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/530373/148510).

Next, there is a change-of-variables theorem for Riemann-Stieltjes integrals (Apostol Theorem 7.7) that justifies

$$\int_0^b f^{-1}(x)\,dx =\int_{0}^{f^{-1}(b)} t\,df(t)$$

Finally, since $f$ is increasing and $\alpha: t \mapsto t $ is continuous, $\alpha$ is Riemann-Stieltjes integrable with respect to $f$. By another well known theorem (Apostol Theorem 7.6), it follows that $f$ is integrable with respect to $\alpha$, and the integration by parts as you have written is valid:

$$\int_{0}^{f^{-1}(b)} t\,df(t) =bf^{-1}(b)-\int_0^{f^{-1}(b)}f(t)\,dt$$

No assumption that $f$ is differentiable is required.

**Change-of-variables**

Apostol's Theorem 7.7 states that

$$\int_{g(c)}^{g(d)} h(x)\, d\alpha(x) = \int_c^d g(h(t)) \, d \alpha(g(t)),$$

if $h$ is integrable with respect to $\alpha$ and $g$ is a strictly monotonic increasing continuous function.

Show how this applies to your question.

Comment: For integration by parts, I thought you needed both your functions to be differentiable (based of baby Rudin's theorem 6.19).

Comment: It is true under weaker conditions. There is also a lot to prove here starting with the change of variables into an RS integral which does not require $f$ to be differentiable.  I can show the way.

Comment: Weaker conditions? Woah, that sounds super sexy lol. Please do.