# Defining $e^x$ and $\ln(x)$ without knowing about integrals

Tags: calculus, logarithms, exponential-function, definition

In my Calculus class I have seen the definition of $\ln(x)$ and $e^x$ like this: First we define
$$
\ln(x) = \int_1^x \frac{1}{t}\; dt
$$
Then we show that $\ln(x)$ is one-to-one. Then we define the inverse of $\ln(x)$ as $e^x$. And so on.

**Is there a meaningful way to define this without using integrals? If so, what is an outline for how this can be done?**

Comment: There is a well-known taylor expansion for $e^x$ : $$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$$ for every real $x$ and $\ln(x)$ is just the inverse of this function, there are series for it as well.

Comment: @Peter: Ok, I guess I should have added not doing with it with Power series as well.

Comment: You may define both as [limits](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/498449/21783) (or just consider 'large' values of $n$).

Comment: You recieved 2 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, consider *accepting* the best answer and upvoting all useful answers you got. That's how the site works.

Comment: @5xum: I accepted an answer. I am not here very often.

Comment: This has been handled many times on this website and in particular on my blog. See [this post](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2014/05/theories-of-exponential-and-logarithmic-functions-part-2_10.html?m=0) for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually like to use the definition I propose below as I think it would be the most natural for anyone new to the topic. First define
$$e=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$
Why is this a good definition? For many it is natural because it arises from a real world example using bank interest.

First important question: Does this limit even exist? If so, why? The answer is yes, and it can be shown by showing that the sequence is bounded (to be exact, $1<e<3$) and increasing, and is well discussed [in this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1334832/prove-limit-converges-in-definition-of-e). By using a transformation $m=nx$, we can see that
$$\exp(x):=e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{nx}=\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{m}\right)^m.$$
From this we can also derive the power series definition of $e^x$. The binomial theorem:
$$(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n {}_{n}\mathrm{C}_k~a^k~b^{n-k}$$
For integer $n$. And even if $n$ is not an integer, if $n$ is sufficiently large we can use the approximation $\lfloor n\rfloor$ which will converge to the same value as $n\to\infty$. Thus,
$$\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n=\left(\frac{x}{n}+1\right)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}\frac{x^k}{n^k}$$
Using a product definition of $n!/(n-k)!$,
$$\left(\frac{x}{n}+1\right)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\left[\prod_{j=1}^k(n-k+j)\frac{x^k}{n^k k!}\right]$$
Since we have $n$ multiplied by iteself $k$ times, we can move it into the product and take the limit:
$$\exp(x)=e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\left[\prod_{j=1}^k\left(\frac{n-k+j}{n}\right)\frac{x^k}{k!}\right]=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}.$$
Since $e>1$, $e^x$ is strictly increasing $\forall x\in \Bbb{R}$ and thus has a unique inverse, as proved in [this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/530373/how-to-show-strictly-increasing-function-on-an-interval-has-continuous-inverse). With this defintion it is easy to show $$\mathrm{D}(\exp)(x)=\exp(x).$$

We can now define the natural log as the inverse of the exponential, that is, $\ln$ is the unique function such that
$$\exp(\ln(x))=\ln(\exp(x))=x ~\forall x\in\mathbb{R}.$$
I suppose the only snag is if we have $x\leq 0$ on the L.H.S. But, in that case we can extend the definition of these functions to complex values and still have consistency. From this we can actually *derive* the integral definition of $\ln$.
$$\mathrm{D}(\exp\circ\ln)(x)=\mathrm{D}(\operatorname{id})(x)$$
$$\exp(\ln(x))\mathrm{D}(\ln)(x)=1$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\ln(x)=\frac{1}{x}$$
$$\ln(x)=\int\frac{1}{x}\mathrm{d}x+C$$
Since $\exp(0)=1$, we can conclude $\ln(1)=0$ and therefore our integral can be written as
$$\ln(x)=\int_1^x \frac{1}{t}\mathrm{d}t.$$

Answer (score 5):

Alternative (and equivalent definitions of $e^x$ include:

$$e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac xn\right)^n$$

$$e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

$$e^x=\lim_{q\to x\\ q\in\mathbb Q} e^q$$

The last definition may appear circular, but it is not. In that last definition, we first define $$e=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$$

Then, for all rational numbers $q\in\mathbb Q$, we define $$e^q=\sqrt[b]{e^a}$$ where $a,b\in\mathbb Z$ are such that $q=\frac ab$.