# Is the pre image of a Connected set by an increasing function also connected set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Formally question:

Consider an increasing function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ (not necessarily continuous), if $I\subset\mathbb{R}$ is connected, then $f^{-1}(I)$ is connected. How I can to proof that question?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: My context is that the connectedness properties under continuous functions are appropriate and under certain discussions I was told that this was true. But under the hypothesis that it is an increasing function it doesn't make sense to me. I have been thinking of supposing that the pre image is not connected, but the hypothesis of being increasing does not help me or I do not know how to use it.

Comment: Connected subsets of the real line must be intervals.

Comment: That is true @Randall, but how to use f increasing in this case?

Comment: Preimages of convex sets are convex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ is (strictly) increasing, [then $f^{-1}$ is continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/530373/how-to-show-strictly-increasing-function-on-an-interval-has-continuous-inverse), and since continuous functions [map connected to connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1573795/proof-of-the-continuous-image-of-a-connected-set-is-connected?rq=1), the result follows.

Comment: That is a great hint , I’m going to write a formal proof. Thank you

Comment: $f^{-1}$ only exists, if $f$ is bijective. However the above also holds, if $f$ is not injective or surjective, see my above comment

Comment: Strictly increasing real functions are invertible

Comment: Certainly not, if they are not surjective. Moreover, the OP did not ask for *strictly* increasing functions.

Comment: Strictly increasing implies surjective. In my answer I assumed that $f$ is strictly increasing and OP verified it - so we can assume OP meant strictly increasing.

Comment: Oh, that's really strange! Just to understand your point: for instance,  $\textrm{exp}: \bf{R} \rightarrow \bf{R}$ is *not* strictly increasing in your opinion? Well, if it's fine for the OP, then it's ok. Just wondering, if someone else stumbles over this question ...

Comment: Ah, strictly increasing doesn't necessarily imply surjective you're right. I should have said it implies injectivity and injectivity implies invertibility from the domain to the image.